# Como puedo autollenar un formulario al escribir la informacion en un input

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, formularios

La verdad soy bastante nuevo en esto, aprendo rápido pero actualmente no he podido encontrar solución a esto.
Tengo una base de datos llamada 'clientes' con la tabla 'datosclientes' y las columnas 'nombre' 'apellido' 'cedula' 'telefono' 'direccion'

Estoy haciendo algo como una factura y necesito hacer que al escribir en un input del formulario ('cedula') se rellenen de forma asíncrona los datos correspondientes en el resto de los inputs,. He logrado algo pero no los coloco en los inputs sino en un div. Aqui mi codigo.

index.php - aqui estan los inputs donde quiero que se muestren

```
        <div id="id-orden">
                <form accept-charset="utf-8" method="POST" action="">

                    <label for="busqueda">Id</label>
                    <input type="text" id="busqueda" autofocus autocomplete="off" onkeyup="buscar();">

                </form>

                    <form action="" id="datoscliente">
                        <label for="nombref">Nombre</label>
                        <input type="text" id="nombref" name="nombref">

                        <label for="apellidof">Apellido</label>
                        <input type="text" id="apellidof" name="apellidof">

                        <label for="telefonof">Telefono</label>
                        <input type="text" id="telefonof" name="telefonof">

                        <label for="direccionf">Direccion</label>
                        <input type="text" id="direccionf" name="direccionf">
                    </form>
```

Este es el div donde se muestran los resultados actualmente

```
<div id="resultadoBusqueda"></div>
```

Script

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>Ingrese cedula</p>');
});

function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();

     if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $.post("buscarinputs.php", {valorBusqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(mensaje) {

            $("input[name='nombref']").val(mensaje.nombre);
            $("input[name='apellido']").val(mensaje.apellido);
            $("input[name='telefonof']").val(mensaje.telefono);
            $("input[name='direccionf']").val(mensaje.direccion);

         }); 
     } else { 
        $("#resultadoBusqueda").html('<p>Ingrese cedula</p>');
        };
};
</script>
```

buscarinputs.php

```
if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

//Selecciona todo de la tabla datosclientes 
//donde cedula sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM datosclientes
WHERE cedula LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda'
");

$filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);


if ($filas === 0) {
    echo json_encode(array('respuesta' => 0));
} else {
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

        echo json_encode($resultado);
    }; //Fin else $filas

};//Fin isset $consultaBusqueda
```

Comment: Solo veo un input en tu código,podreias poner el resto para poder ayudarte mejor? Has probado con asignar el valor del resultado así: $("#busqueda").val(mensaje); ??

Comment: ok, no explique eso, no tengo mas inputs, o sea faltan por colocar, quise mostrar que en ese input es donde se realiza la busqueda y en el div es donde actualmente muestra los resultados.

Comment: probaste $("#busqueda").val(mensaje); ?

Comment: No lo he hecho, acabo de colocar los inputs para que tengas mejor idea, al final se retornan los resultados en html y quiero que se retornen a los inputs que ahora acabo de colocar. Creo que asi esta mas clara la consulta, y disculpa.

Comment: ya probe lo que me indicaste ahora debo terminar de cambiar el script, he intentando sin exito, voy a subir el codigo actualizado

Comment: Es que llamas a mensaje.nombre por ejemplo, pero tu problema está en como entregas los resultados, los estás entregando como una simple cadena de texto, porqué no los entregas en un formato estándar como json, de esta manera puedes parsear el resultado y así acceder a valores como mensaje.nombre y los demás.

Comment: ok entiendo en teoria lo que me dices, y si he tratado de entregarlos con json, solo que no he podido, ahora, aqui es donde necsitaria ayuda

Comment: Puede publicar el valor de la variable mensaje que devuelve supuestamente los resultados en formato jSon?

Comment: Hola, ya lo resolvi, al final coloque echo json_encode($resultado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);

y en el script  var data = JSON.parse(data); y funciona perfecto, muchas gracias por la ayuda

`$.post("../procesos/buscarinputs.php", {busqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(data) {
         var data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            $("#nombref").val(data.nombre);
            $("#apellidof").val(data.apellido);
            $("#telefonof").val(data.telefono);
            $("#direccionf").val(data.direccion);`

Comment: Añádelo correctamente explicado como respuesta así queda bien cerrado el hilo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se resuelve de la siguiente manera. En la consulta php al final se forza un objeto json (puede que sea necesario aveces)

```
 <?php
//Archivo de conexión a la base de datos
require('conexion.php');

//Variable de búsqueda
$consultaBusqueda = $_POST['busqueda'];

//Comprueba si $consultaBusqueda está seteado
if (isset($consultaBusqueda)) {

    //Selecciona todo de la tabla datosclientes 
    //donde cedula sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM clientes
    WHERE cedula LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda' ");
$filas = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);


if ($filas === 0) {
    echo json_encode(array('respuesta' => 0));
} else {
        $resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

        echo json_encode($resultado, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
}; //Fin else $filas

};//Fin isset $consultaBusqueda

?>
```

Y en el script parsear el objeto JSON que se recibe:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


});

function buscar() {
    var textoBusqueda = $("input#busqueda").val();

     if (textoBusqueda != "") {
        $.post("../procesos/buscarinputs.php", {busqueda: textoBusqueda}, function(data) {
            var data = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(data);
            $("#nombref").val(data.nombre);
            $("#apellidof").val(data.apellido);
            $("#telefonof").val(data.telefono);
            $("#direccionf").val(data.direccion);
     }); 
 } else { 
    console.log('error de busqueda');
    };
};
```

Comment: Ten cuidado con esa consulta a la base de datos, por lo visto permite SQL injection